# How to position an image on the page in MS Word

Tags: c#, ms-word

I'm trying to edit a word document via code, just want to Insert two images, one on top left and another on top right of the first page... word.interop documentation states that Word.Range is used to position things.. but im having hard time wrapping my head around how this is used?? How do i specify "top left & Right of first page" Using Word.Range???

doc.InlineShapes.AddPicture(imagePath); which inserts images on top of the document, but dunno how to control position of it further

doc.InlineShapes.AddPicture(imagePath);

I Expect to have to be able to Specify location of images to be at top left and right of page 1.

Answer (score 1):

`.InlineShapes` allows you to add *inline* shapes – shapes that are part of the textual flow.

These shapes are inserted at a range (a position within the text), not absolute coordinates within a page.

To add a shape that does not flow with text, use `.Shapes`.

Comment: Thanks But again, how would i set the shape's position to to page top?

Comment: @AliMMA1 The `Top` property, I should think... You might want to do some in-depth reading in the Word Language Reference.